# How to fix "Object required" error in VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a current code that is supposed to take values from sheet1 and sheet2 and output them into sheet3. The only problem I'm having with this code is that I keep getting "Object required" errors on the :

```
With sheets3
        .Rows(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = sheets1.Rows(myrow)
        End With
```

specifically the .Rows line

Here is the full code:

```
Sub qwerty()
Dim isamatch As Boolean
For myrow = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    isamatch = True
    For mycol = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(myrow, "ZZ").End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        If Sheet1.Cells(myrow, mycol).Value <> Sheet2.Cells(myrow, mycol).Value Then isamatch = False
    Next mycol
    If isamatch Then
        With sheets3
        .Rows(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = sheets1.Rows(myrow)
        End With
    End If
Next myrow
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see where you declared both `sheets3` nor `sheets1` variables. As it is now, those are not declared as sheet objects. Didn't you meant to write: `Sheet3` and `Sheet1`?

Comment: Is `sheets3` the right CodeName for the Sheet you want? Looking at the rest of your code you probably want to use `Sheet3`

Comment: Probably you need to change `sheets3` to `Sheet3` and `sheets1` to `Sheet1`

Comment: it seems I made a silly mistake with the Sheets names that I just couldn't see, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Changed `sheets` to `sheet`

```
Sub qwerty()
Dim isamatch As Boolean
For myrow = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    isamatch = True
    For mycol = 1 To Sheet1.Cells(myrow, "ZZ").End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
        If Sheet1.Cells(myrow, mycol).Value <> Sheet2.Cells(myrow, mycol).Value Then isamatch = False
    Next mycol
    If isamatch Then
        With sheet3
        .Rows(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) = sheet1.Rows(myrow)
        End With
    End If
Next myrow
End Sub
```